# Examples of results first proved using geometrical methods?

Tags: gr.group-theory, big-list, geometric-group-theory

Hi all,

I am beginning to learn about geometric group theory. I would like to write a little exposé intended to be read by the uninitated, so it would be nice to talk about (preferably simple) results which were inaccessible until geometric methods had been applied. Do you have suggestions?

Edit: I would also be interested to hear about results which aren't necessarily inaccessible otherwise, but admit simpler proofs within a geometric approach.

Best to all

Comment: This should be Community Wiki (you'll have to edit your post to make this change) as there's no "right" answer.  Also, your question is a little vague, in that you're basically asking people to tell you about geometric group theory.    Could you narrow it down a bit?  For example, the Wikipedia "Geometric Group Theory" page must partially answer your question -- if so, what else are you looking for? 

Comment: What about the subgroup of a free group is free.

Comment: @Birdman, if you're thinking about the covering space argument, that specific proof technically predates geometric group theory.  Moreover, there were earlier (essentially equivalent) proofs that predated covering space arguments, so such an argument certainly wasn't "inacessible" before geometric group theory. 

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but it seems to veer uncomfortably close to "please write an enyclopaedia entry for me", which I thought we had decided was not MO's metier

Comment: (On 2nd thoughts I am being a bit uncharitable. Nevertheless, I second Ryan's suggestion/request for a more focused question. Maybe something on Bass-Serre theory?)

Comment: I think the OP needs to tell is whether or not the covering-spaces-of-graphs proof that a subgroup of a free group is free is the sort of thing that she is looking for.  It's a great example of the power of geometric thinking for an elementary introduction, but as Ryan observes it's not a result that was by any means inaccessible beforehand.

Comment: ... Almost by definition, any 'simple' results *can* be proved without reference to geometry.

Answer (score 4):

Gromov's theorem that a group of polynomial growth is virtually nilpotent. This still has no algebraic proof to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: This is a good example, but since the definition of "polynomial growth" is geometric, maybe it's not surprising that geometry is an ingredient in the solution. 

Comment: @Agol, although one can, and should, think of growth in terms of balls in the Cayley graph the definition of growth is purely combinatorial.  You are counting the number of elements that have a shortest length representative of size at most n.  People consider growth of other algebraic structures like semigroups and algebras where one doesn't have the corresponding geometry. 

Comment: @Ben: I agree it's combinatorial, but since you used the term "length", you (and others) are clearly thinking of it in a geometric fashion. In fact, I think Milnor originally introduced the notion of growth of groups with geometric applications in mind. A choice of generating set (and therefore Cayley graph) is in some sense a geometric choice, not intrinsic to the group (like the choice of a Riemannian metric on a manifold). The answer "virtually nilpotent" is free of notions of length, which makes the theorem interesting.  

Comment: @Agol, I'm pretty sure that people have used length to describe the number of letters in a word since the time of Post, Thue and Dyck, if not earlier. Length of a word is just a combinatorial notion. But I agree nobody considered growth before Milnor and Svarc, who were geometrically motivated.  But people could have, and the notion is considered for finitely generated algebras.

Answer (score 2):

Dani Wise has [recently proven a conjecture](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/behrstock/cbms/program.html) of Baumslag, that 1-relator groups whose relator is a proper power are residually finite (in fact, linear). The proof makes use of techniques from geometric group theory, in particular using techniques of hyperbolic groups and CAT(0) cube complexes.

Comment: I think this fails at the "preferably simple" stipulation...

Answer (score 2):

The proof of [Stallings's Ends Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups) is topological.  Note that the set of ends of a group $\Gamma$ can be identified with $H^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z}_2\Gamma)$, so you don't have to define ends geometrically.

Comment: Perhaps an even better application is the corollary that groups of cosmological dimension one are free since this is a purely algebraic statement.

Comment: Cosmological should be cohomological.  Somebody should tell me how to remove the autocorrect on iPad.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think one cohomologically-defined invariant (cohomological dimension) is more algebraic than another (ends).  But 'cosmological dimension' is brilliant!

Comment: As you say in your answer ends don't have to be defined geometrically, but they are naturally defined that way.  The cohomological description is not really the natural definition.  On the other hand Stallings original paper on ends was precisely targeted at proving the Eilenberg-Ganea conjecture that groups of cohomological dimension 1 are free.  In other words, a geometric proof is given that the augmentation ideal of a group algebra is projective iff the group is free.

Comment: As I think of the cohomology of a group as the cohomology of an Eilenberg--Mac Lane space, I don't really think that the algebraic definition of cohomological dimension is the 'natural' one either!

Answer (score 1):

I gave an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44269/commutator-subgroup-does-not-consist-only-of-commutators/74345#74345) of a topological proof that a product of two commutators in a free group is not itself always a commutator.  In answer to the same question, Arturo Magidin indicated how to give a combinatorial proof.  I think it's fair to say that the two proofs have completely different flavours, although you can judge for yourself which is 'simpler'.