# A derived group containing more than the commutators

Tags: gr.group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commutator subgroup does not consist only of commutators?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44269/commutator-subgroup-does-not-consist-only-of-commutators)

I am looking for an simple example (i.e. for undergraduate students) of group whose commutators $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ do not form a subgroup.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44269/commutator-subgroup-does-not-consist-only-of-commutators/ .