# Bound on the order of the commutator subgroup based on the number of commutators

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is a known fact that if a group $G$ has finitely many commutators then the order of the commutator subgroup is finite. I have found the following upper bound: Let the number of commutators be equal to $n<\infty$ then $$|G'|< n^{2n^2\log_2(n)}$$
I did this by combining  the best bound given by a proof of Schur's theorem and the best bound given by a proof of the reverse Schur's theorem for finitely generated groups.

This upper bound does not seem very good. Are there better known bounds? For example by using a different method.

Comment: If $G$ has $n < \infty$ commutators, then each conjugacy class in $G$ is of size $\leq n$. Then Theorem 1.8 in [R. M. Guralnick; A. Maróti; Average dimension of fixed point spaces with applications. Adv. Math. 226 (2011), no. 1, 298-308](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3836.pdf) gives $|G'| < n^{(1/2)(7 + \log_2 n)}$.

Comment: Let $u_n$ be the largest cardinal of $|G'|$ for a group with exactly $n$ commutators, and $v_n=\max_{i\le n}u_i$. A (lengthy) verification shows, if I'm correct, that $u_n=n$ for $n\le 4$. Have further values been computed?

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what is $n_0$, the smallest $n$ for which $u_n>n$. The examples [in this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/269162/14094) show that for odd prime $p$ and $n\ge 4$ we have $v_{p^{2n}}>p^{n(n-1)/2}$; thus $n_0\le 3^8=6561$. This also yields $v_n\succeq n^2$. Examples of this flavor might suggest $v_n$ is indeed suprapolynomial, which would make the upper bound in spin's comment quite good.

Comment: For $n=5,6$ it is also the case that $u_n=n$. For higher values I don't know. The first $n$ for which I am aware that $u_n>n$ is 15.

Comment: For finite groups, the smallest groups $G$ such that $G'$ is not equal to the set of commutators have order $|G| = 96$; they have $29$ commutators and $|G'| = 32$. And there are groups of order $|G| = 128$ with $15$ commutators, such that $|G'| = 16$. So $n_0 \leq 15$ as noted by Lucas.

Comment: Theorem D in [R. M. Guralnick; Commutators and commutator subgroups. Adv. in Math. 45 (1982), no. 3, 319-330](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0001-8708(82)80008-X) implies that if $|G'| < 16$, then $G'$ is equal to the set of commutators. So $n_0 = 15$.

Comment: Spin, does that necessarily mean that $n_0=15$? Why couldn't you have a group with, say, 14 commutators with $|G'|\geq 16$?

Comment: @NickGill: I think you are right, it doesn't settle the question. I didn't think that one through. Well, at least $n_0 \leq 15$.